# Aligning last div elements

Tags: html, css

I've tried to align last *div* element / elements using `text-align-last` property but it didn't work. I have much *divs* in the center, but my page is different on each resolution so I can't control if elements will be perfectly and none of them will be in last line alone or so, that's why I want to align them to left.

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ecn8c0pt/

Picture of my site:
[image]

Comment: Provide more details, code, and preferably a jsfiddle!

Comment: add float left to this divs?

Comment: Not so simple, because the parent div is wider and I don't know how many div elements won't fit exactly to the page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding the following CSS will work.

http://jsfiddle.net/ecn8c0pt/1/

```
#gallery h2{
    margin: 0;
    height: 80px; /*Added height for the Heading */
    font-size: 1.1em;
    font-weight: 300;
    color: #33CCFF;
}


.project{
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 0 15px 40px;
    width: 156px; //To show in jsfiddle i reduced the width.
    text-align: left;
    float: left; //MUST CHANGE: Once you align left it will automatically float to left. Also the number of count per row will depends on the window width and div width.
}

.project .thumbnail{
    width: 156px;//To show in jsfiddle i reduced the width.
    height: 144px;
    border-radius: 3px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try adding styles to your CSS like these:
`float:left; 
min-width: 200px;
max-width: 200px;`
and try to fix the `width` for the wrapping `div` tag
for example:
`.wrapper {
   width:1000px;
}`
see in example [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ecn8c0pt/) and try to predict the width now when you control it  good luck!